# Is there a python REPL for Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, read-eval-print-loop

The Clojure/Compojure people have a drop in repl for Google App Engine, do Python people have anything similar? I use the repl quite a bit in "vanilla" python development, and it would be really useful if I could use it in Google App Engine Python as well.

I have seen the following http://shell.appspot.com/ demo, and I was basically hoping there might be a drop-in replacement for any Python App Engine project that gave me a repl; even if the repl only worked against the dev server. Anyone know of such a thing?

[here](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/downloads/list) is the source code to this demo, just for completeness.

Comment: What's wrong with the one you link to? It's fully functional. There's also the remote API shell, which comes with the SDK, if you want a terminal-based repl that can interact with your production site.

Comment: There's a shell at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/ for localhost. @Wooble I think he wants one inside his own app, not in a standalone app.

Comment: @Nick: right, but he links to the source to shell.appspot.com, which can be integrated into existing projects easily...

Comment: @Wooble True. @Stephen Why not just include the shell? I think it's even in google.appengine.ext, no need to include your own code, just a handler.

Comment: Actually, I should have been a little more specific. I am looking for a repl that I could use within emacs. I was really kind of thinking of something like a repl that I could log into from the terminal. So that I could use screen to edit the repl with other developers.

Comment: One option is to use dev_appserver.py, and navigate to http://localhost:8000/console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with a REPL that works on the dev server, take a look at the `bin/python` script that [Tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) creates for you. It just loads the Python REPL with your project and the GAE SDK code. I've pasted my version of it [here](https://gist.github.com/1046676) - YMMV, but you can use it as a starting point.